# Append $(this).info to Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I'm building a webshop and it has a couple of items on it, each of these items have a unique image, a name and a price. When I press the first item, I want to append that items image, that items price, and that items name to my modal. As of now, all I can append is the unique images, now I seek help here because I've been stuck for a while. 
This is the JS I've got so far.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        //STORE ITEM--------------------------------------------------------------->
        var $productItem = $(".storeItem");
        var $productPrice = $(".productPrice");
        $productItem.addClass("large-4 small-6 columns");

        //MODAL POPUP-------------------------------------------------------------->
        var $myModal = $(".reveal-modal");
        var $imageContainer = $('.imageContainer');
        var $productPriceContainer = $("#productPriceContainer");
        var $productNameContainer = $("#productNameContainer");

        $imageContainer.addClass("large-4 small-12 columns");


        //ADD THE IMAGES AND INFO TO THE PRODUCT---------------------------------->

        $(function() {

            $productItem.click(function(){

        });

        $('.storeItem a img').click(function() {
            if ($(".imageContainer:contains('img')")) {
                $imageContainer.empty();
            }

            $img=$(this).attr('src');
            $imageContainer.append("<img src="+$img+" />");
        });
    });
});
```

As per request, the HTML. :

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
    <div class = "imageContainer"></div>
    <h2 id = "productNameContainer"></h2>
    <p id = "productPriceContainer"></p>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>


    <div class="storeItem">
        <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">
            <img src="http://designspiration.net/data/l/423341110329_Qy737Vid_l.jpg">
            <div class ="panel">
                 <h5 class="productName">Kotthållare</h5>
                 <h6 class="productPrice">$99.90</h6>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Thanks for your help. It's very appreciated. 
I'd also appreciate if you explained your thinking behind your answer so that I can learn from it. :)

Regards
David

Comment: can you include some HTML?

Comment: There, some HTML. :) Well, the HTML I'm working with.

Comment: Just to point out $(document).ready(function(){ is EXACTLY the same as $(function(){, which is shorthan. You do not need both in your script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the HTML, in this case just some text or numbers, in the h5 and h6 with

```
$name= $(this).parent('div a').find('.productName').html();
$price= $(this).parent('div a').find('.productPrice').html();
```

after that you just have to append it whereever you want

[here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/28HtR/)

Comment: No, if I do that, it will append all the prices of all of the items. Isn't that correct?

Comment: this was just an example, but you are right. If you want to get one from a specific `.storeItem` you could specify it. If i got you right you want the click-event **only** on the `img`, right?

Comment: I want to take a specific price from the item I click. So, some form of $(this).productPrice, seems to be in order, I just don't know how to do that.

Comment: You could use jquerys `.parent()` [link](https://api.jquery.com/parent/). This way you can travel back from your `img` to the parrent `div.storeItem`. I would make a fiddle if i would have free time right now... but yhea.

Comment: Would you mind having a go at it when you actually DO have time? I'm not working on the site at this very moment anyways. I've gone completely mad about this. I even tried to put a $(this) method inside the img-click to control the price at one point, haha.

Comment: hehe yhea sure I will in 4 hours when im back home ^^